# Stripping URLs from String

Tags: java, regex

I would like to strip all forms of URLs from a string if they start with whether they start with `.*://` or `www.*` but having trouble adding the regex to a pre-existing complex pattern.

Currently, I use

```
public static String censorUrls(String str) {

        String urlPattern = "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|Unsure|http):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(urlPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

        int i = 0;

        while ( matcher.find() ) {

            str = str.replaceAll(matcher.group(i), "****").trim();

            i++;

        }

    return str;

}
```

However, this doesn't help with URLs that may just be `www.google.com` or `google.com` or even `www3.site.com`

Comment: How do you know `google.com` is a URL? Is `$12.50` a URL?

Comment: Technically, `www.example.com` isn’t a URL. A URL requires the protocol. A file or a folder may follow that pattern with impunity. Also, why do you have `?` after the first `https`? Finally, all those back slashes — are you looking for Windows patterns? A proper URL uses forward slashes, even on Windows.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But, I would rather censor a typo though than have URLs past to children. And the pattern I am using is re-purposed. I'm not even sure of it's definitive meaning (towards the end of the pattern) Those backslashes are again from the original code which is not created by me. Also, when I remove some, it tells me i need to escape in Eclipse.

Comment: That's because backslash is a special character that needs to be escaped by another backslash. They need to be added and removed in pairs.

Comment: Is this crucial to the question? Currently, the function works fine for what it can do. It just doesn't remove all types of posted url types where `www.somesite.com` and `somesite.com` are parsed into a link by the chat system, and must be stripped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't remember where this came from, but you can try it.

If it's mid-string matches or not, you might be able to use this one.
This uses whitespace boundaries. `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` and will match at anchor
positions as well.

Raw: `(?i)(?<!\S)(?!mailto:)(?:[a-z]*://)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))|localhost)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?(?!\S)`

Stringed: `"(?i)(?<!\\S)(?!mailto:)(?:[a-z]*://)?(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\\x{a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\x{a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\x{a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\x{a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\x{a1}-\\x{ffff}]{2,})))|localhost)(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:\\/[^\\s]*)?(?!\\S)"`

Formatted:

```
 (?i)
 (?<! \S )
 (?! mailto: )
 (?:
      [a-z]* :
      \/\/
 )?
 (?:
      \S+ 
      (?: : \S* )?
      @
 )?
 (?:
      (?:
           (?:
                [1-9] \d? 
             |  1 \d\d 
             |  2 [01] \d 
             |  22 [0-3] 
           )
           (?:
                \.
                (?: 1? \d{1,2} | 2 [0-4] \d | 25 [0-5] )
           ){2}
           (?:
                \.
                (?:
                     [1-9] \d? 
                  |  1 \d\d 
                  |  2 [0-4] \d 
                  |  25 [0-4] 
                )
           )
        |  (?:
                (?: [a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+ -? )*
                [a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+ 
           )
           (?:
                \.
                (?: [a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+ -? )*
                [a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+ 
           )*
           (?:
                \.
                (?: [a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,} )
           )
      )
   |  localhost
 )
 (?: : \d{2,5} )?
 (?: \/ [^\s]* )?
 (?! \S )
```

Comment: It sure looks complex. I tried to test it online and Java Regular Expression tester gives a bunch of errors, so I tried to paste it into Eclipse and there were no errors so I decided to compile and run. It doesn't give any errors, but it doesn't seem to strip any urls of any sort. `http://google.com` or otherwise.

Comment: Well, it matches `http://google.com` did you try to _replace_ with the empty string?

Comment: Oh hey never-mind. It works fine. Problem was it being so long of a string I accidentally threw in a character off screen and didn't realize. Much appreciated. Seems to work fine.

Comment: I added a _raw_ version if you want to use that in an online tester.

Comment: Thanks. I have to say this was a apparently a **lot** harder than I realized.

Comment: Yeah, this is just a _tiny_ url regex. The really big ones are like 5k in length. But, for url's, the better validation means less false positives.